# Regarding Netty and Apache NIO

Tags: tomcat

I was reading Netty and Apache documentation in terms of how they respond to the request. My current understanding is:

1. Tomcat 1 : Creates one thread per request
2. Tomcat 2: Creates one thread for multiple requests
3. Any Java NIO( Netty, Grizzly, undertow etc.) based web containers : Create one thread for multiple requests

But, how these NIO based web servers handles user session. For ex. I have a Jersey Shiro service which authenticates a user but if same thread is handling multiple requests, is it possible to get one users' information in another thread. Am I missing any concept here?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course it's possible, otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you, so, how I make sure that the user information is not being shared in a particular security context with other threads?